# EF6 - Add item to collection without eager loading the collection

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I'm sure this has been answered before but I'm unable to find a reasonable solution. So the problem is I am using a generic repository that exposes IQueryable methods. I am trying to add an item to a models collection without the need to `Include(x => x.collection)`. If I do not include the collection then the model collection is null (naturally). But this means I have to create a new collection and add the item that way. Which interferes with the existing collection in the DB.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Current code:

```
UserProfile creator = await repo.Get(x => x.UserId == session.CreatorId)
           .Include(x => x.Notifications).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

...

creator.Notifications.Add(notification);
```

Comment: You can try to do this update from direction of your collection, will that fit you? `notification.Creator = creator`. I believe this won't make you load `creator.Notifications`.

Comment: @raderick So insert directly into the notifications table with the foreign key to the user profile, rather than adding to the collection? If that's what you mean then yeah I believe that would work :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I'm aftaid there's no another easy way to do this.

Comment: You mentioned " Which interferes with the existing collection in the DB." - did you mean it would remove existing entries? I don't think that is the case. Did you test it?

Comment: @dugas Yeah, when I set notifications = new List<Notifications>() it would delete the existing entities in the database.

Comment: That is different behavior than I have witnessed (just tested on EF6). It actually sends deletes for existing entities when you look at the sql sent to the database?

Comment: After closer inspection it doesn't actually delete the records, but the next time I Include the collection of notifications I get an empty collection... Not sure why, but raderick gave me a different perspective to work from.